# Is it possible to invoke a method from abstract class?

Tags: android, methods, abstract-class

I have the Abstract class as following:

AbstractFilePickerFragment.java

```
public abstract class AbstractFilePickerFragment<T> extends ListFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<T>>

....

....

public void GoBackToPreviousDirectory() {
    currentPath = getParent(currentPath);
    refresh();
  }
}
```

OtherActivity.java

```
private AbstractFilePickerFragment<T> mAbstractFilePickerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

   //THIS LINE SAYS "Cannot instantiate the type AbstractFilePickerFragment"
    mAbstractFilePickerFragment = new AbstractFilePickerFragment();
}

    public void GoBackToPreviousDir_onClick(MenuItem item) {
        mAbstractFilePickerFragment.GoBackToPreviousDirectory();
    }
}
```

Does anyone if it is possible to invoke the GoBackToPreviousDirectory from AbstractFilePickerFragment class???

I know a static method would work, but I can't make a static method for this situation.

Thank you so very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a non-static method, you have to instantiate the class.

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, by definition. So Answer is NO

If you still need to access the method, You will have to create a class that extends the abstract class and implement all of the methods in the class. Then you can instantiate the extended class within your program and call the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Can you give me an example or link of "a class that extends the abstract class and implement all of the methods in the class?"

Answer (score 3):

No. First, you do not invoke methods from **classes**. You invoke **object**  methods as object is **instance** of class. Abstract class cannot be instantiated.